# В Google Play Console обновили приложение на 50 процентов. При этом новому пользователю будет предлагаться новая версия приложения или старая?

Tags: google-play-console, публикация-приложений, обновление-приложений

В Google Play Console обновили приложение на 50 процентов.
При этом новому пользователю будет предлагаться новая (обновленная) версия приложения или старая (предыдущая)?

Пояснение. Когда мы обновляем приложение в Google Play Console, нам всегда предлагается указать - для какого процента пользователей сделать данное обновление: от 1 до 100 процентов...

Comment: что означает "на 50%"?

Comment: @Эникейщик Когда мы обновляем приложение в Google Play Console, нам всегда предлагается указать - для какого процента пользователей сделать данное обновление: от 1 до 100 процентов